# Proving maximum value of a determinant of $I - B$, where $B$ is nonnegative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following setting:

Let $0 \leq r < 1$ and let $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^k$ be $k$ complex numbers such that $|z_i| \leq r$ for all $i$.
Moreover, $r + \sum_{i=1}^k 2Re(z_i) \geq 0$

I am interested to know if the following is true:

$(1-r)\prod_{i=1}^k |1-z_i|^2 \leq 1$.

The above stems from trying to bound the determinant of $I-B$ where $B$ is nonnegative. One can think of $z_i$ being the complex eigenvalues of $B$ and the reason for $|1-z_i|^2$ is due to complex eigenvalues coming in conjugate pairs for real matrices. Also, $r$ is the spectral radius of the nonnegative $B$, and $r + \sum_{i=1}^k 2Re(z_i) \geq 0$ is due to the trace of a nonnegative matrix being nonnegative.

All ideas I have so far yield an upper bound greater than $1$, and I thought the expression was false. However, using Mathematica I could not find a counterexample to this, which makes me think it could be true.
The main ideas I used: triangle inequality, and arithmetic-geometric ineq., but could not get the 1 upper bound or a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general. E.g., take any $r\in(0,1)$ and let
$$z_i:=x+iy,\quad x:=-\frac r{2k},\quad 
y:=r\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{{4k^2}}}$$
for all $i$.
Then all the conditions on $r$ and $z_i$'s hold, whereas
$$(1-r)\prod_{i=1}^k|1-z_i|^2=(1-r)(1+r^2+r/k)^k\to\infty \not\le 1$$
as $k\to\infty$.

Alternatively, let
$$z_i:=ir$$
for all $i$. Then all the conditions on $r$ and $z_i$'s hold, whereas
$$(1-r)\prod_{i=1}^k|1-z_i|^2=(1-r)(1+r^2)^k\to\infty \not\le 1$$
as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A follow-up question: is it possible to construct a non-negative matrix based on those eigenvalues? My original problem was actually to find the upperbound to the determinant of $I-B$, where B is nonnegative. I assumed that it was enough to assume that the leading eigenvalue of $B$ is real and the rest are complex eigenvalues. I wonder if this argument was OK or this would be wrong.

Comment: @Bee : Your follow-up question about the determinant is unclear to me. Such questions should be asked, not in comments, but in separate, carefully prepared posts (possibly not on MathOverflow). Moreover, asking multiple questions in one post is discouraged on MathOverflow. So, let us finalize this matter accordingly.